# Prove that $C_c(R^n )$ is not a closed subspace of $L^∞(R^n )$, is dense in $C_0(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have difficulty to find a counterexample for the not clousure in $L^{\infty}$

Comment: Hint: a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**:

(1) To visualise, consider $n=1$.

(2) To see that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not closed in $L^\infty$, consider a sequence of functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with support becoming arbitrarily large and converging to a constant non-zero function.

(3) The density of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ follows because if $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x$ outside a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, you can approximate $f$ by a $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function by making $f$ have  value $0$ outside this compact set, of course preserving continuity.